# Composite Cassandra Key in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-cassandra

I have a Cassandra cluster created using the following :

```
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS activitylogs WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'}  AND durable_writes = true;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS activitylogs.activities (
        activity_id timeuuid,
        actor_id text,
        app_id text,
        item_id text,
        viewer_id text,
        activity_type int,
        ts timestamp,
        PRIMARY KEY (actor_id, activity_id, app_id)
    ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (activity_id DESC, app_id ASC);

INSERT INTO activities (activity_id,actor_id, app_id, item_id, viewer_id, activity_type) VALUES ( now(), 'fsdgs346-sdsd5-4242','blossom','ff235-fsd54-fadsfdfs45','hj923hjn-2jnkl23-323yfh',0);
```

I am using Eclipse with the following build.gradle:

```
group 'com.abc'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.5.RELEASE")
    }
}

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-serving-web-content'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
     compile "org.springframework.data:spring-data-cassandra:1.4.6.RELEASE"
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.6'
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.0.13'
    testCompile "junit:junit"
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

Now, I wrote the following entity:

```
package com.abc.activitystream.entity;

import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.PrimaryKey;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Table;

import java.security.Timestamp;

@Table(value = "activities")
public class Activity
{

    /*CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS activitylogs.activities (
    activity_id timeuuid,
    actor_id text,
    app_id text,        
    item_id text,
    viewer_id text,
    activity_type int,
    ts timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (actor_id, activity_id, app_id)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (activity_id DESC);*/

    @PrimaryKey
    private ActivityKey ak;

    @Column(value = "item_id")
    private String item_id;

    @Column(value = "viewer_id")
    private String viewer_id;

    @Column(value = "activity_type")
    private int activity_type;

    @Column(value = "ts")
    private Timestamp ts;

    public String getItem_id() {
        return item_id;
    }

    public void setItem_id(String item_id) {
        this.item_id = item_id;
    }

    public String getViewer_id() {
        return viewer_id;
    }

    public void setViewer_id(String viewer_id) {
        this.viewer_id = viewer_id;
    }

    public int getActivity_type() {
        return activity_type;
    }

    public void setActivity_type(int activity_type) {
        this.activity_type = activity_type;
    }

    public Timestamp getTs() {
        return ts;
    }

    public void setTs(Timestamp ts) {
        this.ts = ts;
    }

    public ActivityKey getAk() {
        return ak;
    }

    public void setAk(ActivityKey ak) {
        this.ak = ak;
    }
}
```

Because the table uses a composite primary key, I had to use the following structure as mentioned here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/1.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/cassandra.core.html

So my ActivityKey class is such:

```
@PrimaryKeyClass
public class ActivityKey implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "actor_id",ordinal = 0,type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String actor_id;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name="activity_id",ordinal = 1,type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED, ordering = Ordering.DESCENDING )
    private UUID activity_id = UUIDs.timeBased();

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name="app_id", ordinal = 2, type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED, ordering = Ordering.ASCENDING)
    private String app_id;

    public String getActor_id() {
        return actor_id;
    }

    public void setActor_id(String actor_id) {
        this.actor_id = actor_id;
    }

    public UUID getActivity_id() {
        return activity_id;
    }

    public void setActivity_id(UUID activity_id) {
        this.activity_id = activity_id;
    }

    public String getApp_id() {
        return app_id;
    }

    public void setApp_id(String app_id) {
        this.app_id = app_id;
    }

    @Override
      public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((actor_id == null) ? 0 : actor_id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((app_id == null) ? 0 : app_id.hashCode());
        return result;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
          return true;
        if (obj == null)
          return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
          return false;
        ActivityKey other = (ActivityKey) obj;
        if (actor_id == null) {
          if (other.actor_id != null)
            return false;
        } else if (!actor_id.equals(other.actor_id))
          return false;
        if (app_id == null) {
          if (other.app_id != null)
            return false;
        } else if (!app_id.equals(other.app_id))
          return false;
        return true;
      }

}
```

My Controller is this:

```
@RestController
public class ActivityController {

    @Autowired
    private ActivityRepository activityRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/activity",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Activity> activity() {
        List<Activity> activities = new ArrayList<>();
        activityRepository.findAll().forEach(e->activities.add(e));
        return activities;
    }
```

}

Finally the repository is this:

```
public interface ActivityRepository extends CassandraRepository<Activity> {

    @Query("SELECT*FROM activities WHERE actor_id=?0 LIMIT ?1")
    Iterable<Activity> findByActor_Id(String actor_id,Integer limit);

}
```

Strangely, the application doesn't run and quits with the following error:

Error creating bean with name 'greetingController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.rg.cassandraspring.repository.ActivityRepository com.rg.cassandraspring.controller.GreetingController.activityRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'activityRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.VerifierMappingExceptions: java.security.cert.CertPath:
Cassandra entities must have the @Table, @Persistent or @PrimaryKeyClass Annotation

Finally this is my CassandraConfig:

```
@Configuration
//@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:META-INF/cassandra.properties"})
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = {"com.abc"})
public class CassandraConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CassandraConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {

        CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
        cluster.setContactPoints("localhost");
        cluster.setPort(Integer.parseInt("9042"));
        return cluster;
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraMappingContext mappingContext() {
        return new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraConverter converter() {
        return new MappingCassandraConverter(mappingContext());
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraSessionFactoryBean session() throws Exception {

        CassandraSessionFactoryBean session = new CassandraSessionFactoryBean();
        session.setCluster(cluster().getObject());
        session.setKeyspaceName("activitylogs");
        session.setConverter(converter());
        session.setSchemaAction(SchemaAction.NONE);

        return session;
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraOperations cassandraTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new CassandraTemplate(session().getObject());
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me this ? I can't seem to put my finger on the problem.

Comment: Of note, the error vanishes when I use a single field PrimaryKey

Comment: ^ then it could be issue with `UUID` field.. you can try changing to String for testing..

Comment: No change, same error previals/

Comment: java.security.Timestamp is not Date  you should be using java.util.Date for cassandra datatype timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seemed to be of 'Timestamp' type to represent the 'ts' column of the table 'activities'. I changed that to 'Date' from java.util and everything seems to run just fine.

I haven't had the time to look into the reason though yet.

Answer (score 2):

Not completly related to your question, spring docs state, that when you want to store time Object in your entity, you should use:

- Joda-Time: DateTime
- legacy Java Date and Calendar
- JDK8 date and time types
- long or Long

More info here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#auditing.annotations